# Get coordinates of each group in svg with getbBox not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, coordinates

How can I get the coordinates of each group with an id inside the svg?

I keep getting the error: **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

What is the correct way to do this?

```
       $("svg").find("g[id]").each(function(){

            var xPos = $(this).getBBox().x;
            var yPos = $(this).getBBox().y;

            console.log($(this).attr('id').getBBox().x);

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(this) gets you a jquery object. You want the native DOM which is $(this)[0] so your code would be

```
var xPos = $(this)[0].getBBox().x;
```

etc